# Обновление списка в адаптере не срабатывает при обновлении элемента в базе Room через ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, viewmodel, livedata

Есть список в `RecyclerView` во фрагменте. Заполняется с `Room` через `ViewModel`.

Если добавляю запись в бд:

```
@Insert
fun insert(item: Item);
```

То фрагмент получает изменения и обновляет адаптер:

```
myViewModel.allItems.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { myItemList ->
    myItemList?.let {

        Log.d("TAG", "DF myItemList.size = " + myItemList.size)
        adapter.setItemList(it)
    }
})
```

Но если пытаюсь ОБНОВИТЬ какую-то запись, то никаких обновлений не получаю.

```
@Update(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE) 
fun update(item: Item)
```

Лог во фрагменте срабатывает только если вставляю новий элемент в базу.

Не могу понять что я не подключил.

Видимо есть разница в реализации `fun update()` и `fun insert`. Но найти информацию именно по этой проблеме не смог пока.

Comment: Должно работать... У вас точно что-то меняется в таблице при вызове `Update`?

Comment: Попробуйте обновить через инсерт @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)

Comment: @Valeriy Как раз и хотел уже так делать, но перебрал снова код и нашел свою ошибку. Заодно был опечален тем что студия молчала. А вроде бы как должна была выкинуть ошибку.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Перебрал код,  и нашел что не все поля передал в объект который передавал в `fun update()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в том что передавая объект в `fun update(item: Item)` нужно обязательно передавать значение `PrimaryKey`. Так как именно по значению `PrimaryKey` происходит поиск строки которую нужно изменить в базе.
В противном случае данная строка не будет найдена.
И как оказалось, ошибки `AndroidStudio` не выбрасывает ни при компиляции ни при непосредственно выполнении запроса.